# Is there a website that shows past flight tracks of a few days back?

Tags: online-tracking, flight-tracking

I'm looking for a website, like Flight Radar, that can display the positions of aircraft going back a few days (i.e. not a live map)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need a few days then FlightAware let’s you do that. I think it goes back 7 days for free. Past that you have to pay. That is for a particular flight. FR24 has a history feature that will play back the whole radar starting at a particular time. It plays back at 12x speed, though.

On FR24 you just open the main screen, move the map where you want it then click the clock icon on the right side. Enter the time and date you’re interested in. Note that it’s in UTC time, so you’ll have to convert your local time to UTC.

[image]

Then it will begin playing back. You can see the time and playback speed on a bar at the bottom of the screen.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - where is this feature on Flight Aware?

Comment: Just search for the flight number. It will bring up th most recent one.then there’s a link above the map that says “see flight schedule.” Tap on that then select the one you want

Comment: I should have mentioned that I don't know the flight number, but I do know where and when it flew overhead.

Comment: Then you can use the FR24 function to play back the radar at the time to find the flight num. I’ll edit some instructions into my answer