# Data for mapping a past flight?

Tags: gnss, online-tracking, flight-tracking

[Is there a website that shows past flight tracks of a few days back?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52278/is-there-a-website-that-shows-past-flight-tracks-of-a-few-days-back) tells how to use FlightAware to see a past flight on a map.  But is there any public source of times/coordinates for past flights?

I found one site that apparently allows download of a KML file for paid subscribers.  I’m interested in GPX (or other formats I can convert to GPX) so that I can **add** a flight I took to GPX files showing my other modes of travel on the same day.

Example: I used my phone to map my route from Rockaway Beach to JFK and my path out of DFW.  I would like to paste in the path of AA2234 on that date.  (Phone can't get a good GPS signal inside the plane.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FlightAware has a KML download, it's buried under a "google earth button". The image below shows an example from [an AAL2234 flight](https://www.flightaware.com/live/flight/AAL2234/history/20231125/1310Z/KJFK/KDFW/tracklog), it's downloadable even without a login.  Login is only required for flights too far in the past.  Longer history can be purchased (more than a hundred US dollars).

[image]

Comment: Perfect!  I was able to change the date and download the KML for the flight I took.  Took me a while to figure out how to get one for another flight.  Have to go to the flight for the date in question, and then click "View track log."  Can't merely edit the URI because it contains a UTC time and I don't know how to determine the time to use for a particular flight.  If you know how, perhaps edit that into your answer.  If not, perhaps add the info about the "view" link.

Comment: By the way, if the KML were not there, it would be rather trivial for me to convert the table of times and positions to GPX.  Even more trivial to let GPSVisualizer.com do the conversion.