# Finding schedule of four-year-old flight

Tags: online-tracking, flight-tracking, flight-schedules

I've somehow lost the data of flights I took 24 Feb 2020.  Current schedules do not show any flights that would fit my approximate times.

I don't have the flight number, but I know that it left EUG **after** 05:10 (12:10 UTC) and arrived at SEA **before** 08:44 (15:44 UTC) and was a Delta fare, confirmation GUVBMT.  The next leg (same ticket) was SEA-DEN that let the SEA gate about 15:44 UTC.

**Is there a way to get the planned or actual flight times for a date that far back?**

[GPX for the flight path](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/101916/data-for-mapping-a-past-flight) would be even better, but [not willing to pay for it](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/101948/11555).

Comment: DHS should have it, but when I made an FOIA request for my PCR data, all I got was _some_ of my international flights, with some of those wrong!